# Related Rates Question with right-circular cylinder

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The Question is

> The radius of a right-circular cylinder is increasing at the rate of $1/2$ in/min. At a specific instant the radius and altitude of the cylinder are $5$ inches and $20$ inches. What should be the rate of change in the altitude of the cylinder in order for the volume to remain constant.

Given

$\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{2}~\dfrac{\text{inches}}{\text{min}}$

$r = 5$ inches

$h = 20$ inches

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = 0$

RTF

$\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ (has to be negative)

Work

\begin{align*}
v & = \pi r^2h\\ 
\frac{dv}{dt} & = 2πrh \frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{dh}{dt} \pi r^2\\  
-\frac{dh}{dt} \pi r^2 & = 2πrh \frac{dr}{dt}\\  
-\frac{dh}{dt} & = \frac{2h}{r} \frac{dr}{dt}\\  
-\frac{dh}{dt} & = \frac{(2)(0.5)(20)}{5}\\  
-\frac{dh}{dt} & = 4~\frac{\text{inches}}{\text{min}}  
\end{align*}

I'm just wondering if that is correct or if I made a mistake somewhere and I am not catching it. Thank you very much for reading

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: we expect questions to be properly formatted in LaTeX.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It was not clear that the rate of change of the height was to be calculated at a specific moment. "What should be the rate of change in the altitude of the cylinder in order for the volume to remain constant." "The volume remains" constant does not mean to me that its derivative is zero for a tiny moment.